# Just lost 90 rep, but I got an Enlightened badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, enlightened-badge

I'm wondering if something just got updated.  Not sure why I lost 90 rep, but got a new Enlightened badge for a really old answer.

Comment: Seems like you must have lost 100 rep somewhere (+10 from the vote which gave you the enlightened badge -100 ==> -90). Maybe something with associating/disassociating your accounts?

Comment: My rep's been jumping around this week a bit.  +51 a few days ago, -49 just now, I have no idea where I'd look to see what changed.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, -100 might also come from a post which has automatically been deleted by gathering enough flags. Might that be the case?

Comment: Perhaps, have you ever cast bounties on Community Wiki posts? One recalc accidentally returned all of that reputation, so a new recalc was just run last night and today which reverted that effect.

Comment: My activity has been fairly low over the past month (been busy).  I dont think I've disassociated any accounts.  I'm not sure how to tell if old posts have been deleted which would cause the -100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exact rep change was 95, due to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481482/should-i-publish-my-project-as-open-source/1481504#1481504) (10K View only) to an off-topic question that was deleted since your last recalc.  It had 8 upvotes and was accepted, accounting for the 95 rep difference.

Comment: That 80 rep post is also accepted answer, so total 95 alone on that post

Comment: @YOU - oo right, my quick aggregation query isn't looking for that, updating.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  Gotta love moderator power... or not.

Answer (score 1):

*"In order to gain anything you must first lose everything"*

-- some wise guy

Comment: haha, thankfully I havent lost everything